# Auth:attempt cant login after verification

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3

once my user is verified when logging in they are hit with this warning Invalid user credentials, please try again! i don't know how to fix this!

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->pass], true)) {

        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
```

my user table -

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password' , 64);
        $table->tinyInteger('verified')->default(0); // this column will be a TINYINT with a default value of 0 , [0 for false & 1 for true i.e. verified]
        $table->string('email_token')->nullable(); // this column will be a VARCHAR with no default value and will also BE NULLABLE
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Does `$request->pass` is hashed?

Comment: how do you mean ?

Comment: @DeadRespawn Is the password hashed with bcrypt in the database? If you create an user you should use the `bcrypt($yourpassword)` function to hash the users password. The attempt function expects a crypted password in the database.

Comment: ok where do i check for this ?

Answer (score 0):

As Siliace said, your password need to be bcrypted.
You can check this by:

```
dd($request->input('pass'));
```

If you see what you typed - you need to `bcrypt($request->input('pass'));`

I don't sure, but I think you have $request is instance of Request. 
So access to input fields is: `$request->input('email')` and `$request->input('pass')`.